# /var/log/journal created automatically when using systemd?

Tags: systemd-journald

Is /var/log/journal created automatically if you are using systemd services? After reading the man page on journal, I noticed that you need to specifically enable persistent storage by editing the .conf file and manually creating the folder /var/log/journal but I noticed that most of my Ubuntu hosts already have this folder when I never configured it. The only thing I know is that I am using systemd services.

Is this the default behavior?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 mostly.